# Raspberry doesn't show the desktop through VNC viewer

Tags: ssh, vnc, desktop

I'm trying to connect to my raspberry pi through VNC Viewer. It connects perfectly (it is connected to my router, and I'm able to connect both via VNC and SSH). The only issue that it appears is that it doesn't show me the desktop. What appears in VNC Viewer is that it cannot currently show the desktop.

Comment: If its not connected to a monitor you may need to set a resolution in 'sudo raspi-config'

Comment: Did you remember to enable VNC in "Interfaces" in Raspberry PI Configuration?

Comment: @CoderMike I already tried that but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: @bashBedlam yes, that has been done.

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi OS 32bit? What resolution did you set?